# How to simulate Ctrl + Shift + f1 in swing application and write to log file

Tags: java, swing, awtrobot

I have this swing client-server app.

I want to simulate the '**Ctrl+Shift+f1**' effect programatically and write to my log4j log file **for certain frames** that I am loading for debugging purposes. Is there a swing method I call to turn this option on? How do I do this?

Or is there a better way to know the layout while it loads and write to log file?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Robot for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "know the layout while it loads"? You can use robot quite easily to simulate key presses as pointed out above.

Comment: No, that never occoured to me, will try it. May be my question is not clear, I updated the question. I want to simulate programatically. If this can be achieved using Robot then great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate key presses quite easily using the Robot class, it has methods to [press and release keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29).

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```